# How to have variable defaults in templates?

Tags: python, django, templates, django-templates

I want to pass variable `defaults` to my templates in case of the actual variable is `None`.

Here is what I mean:

```
{{ value|default:"Default" }}   ## General case.
```

How can I replace `"Default"` with my custom variable ?

Is it possible to replace it with another variable ?

Something like :

```
{{ value|default:{{value2}} }}     ## OR Something similar
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just put another variable instead of constant string like this:

```
{{ value|default:backup_var }}
```

I've just tested this, it works fine. Here is my template piece:

```
<i>{{ my_var|default:user.username}}</i>
```

I have no `my_var` defined, so it evaluates to:

```
<i>admin</i>
```

Summing up, django parser accepts not only constant values, but also variables as parameters to filters also. But not expressions (I couldn't figure out how to make my expression parsed. But if you need it, you may alsways use `{% with var=expr %} ... {% endwith %}` for complex situations)

Comment: Hey, this is great. Simpler than what I thought.